# Period To Date Median Over Time

Tags: visualization, median, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to calculate in Quicksight the median over time on a quarterly bases, so given these values:

| Value | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 |
| 2 | 01/02/2023 |
| 3 | 01/02/2023 |
| 4 | 01/02/2023 |
| 5 | 01/03/2023 |
| 6 | 01/04/2023 |
| 7 | 01/04/2023 |
| 8 | 01/05/2023 |

Ideally I would like to get these values:

| Value | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/2023 |
| 2.5 | 02/2023 |
| 3 | 03/2023 |
| 6.5 | 04/2023 |
| 7 | 05/2023 |

---

There are some functions in Quicksight (like `periodToDateAvgOverTime()`) that perform this aggregation for other functions. Is there a way to calculate this with a custom formula or some work around?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `periodToDateAvgOverTime(median(value),....)`, or use the `mediaIf(value,condition)` and use the date as condition